# Is it RESTful to limit resource properties?

Tags: rest

Our resources consists of dozens of fields (attributes). Some of our clients don't need all resource's properties. To save network payload we implemented a query string parameter to limit the resource properties.
So for example, the next URL will return a collection of resources with all their fields:

http://myapp/myresources

But when the client needs only specific fields he can do that by calling:

http://myapp/myresources?fields=f1,f2,f13,f22

Our architect argues that this approach is not RESTful.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be RESTful if you implemented it as new media types (representations) of the same resource. It would be an incomplete representation, but still, a representation. Let's say you have this resource:

/myapp/myresources

which is a collection of complete representations of some kind of resource.
It's perfectly ok to have a different representation of the same collection. However, if you want it to be REST compliant, you should implement it as a new media type (format).

Then, you can query the collection with Accept header set to your desired media type, or you can use "media type in extension style" - eg. /myapp/myresources.f1_f2_f3.

Your situation is a bit tricky, since your media types would be invented on the fly, but I think it's not impossible.

Comment: Interesting idea, but wouldn't it be complicated for the client? we support both ATOM, XML & JSON representations. Should the client supply the fields in addition to the accept type?

Comment: You can add parameters to Accept header, too. So, your media type can look like this:  xml/summary;fields=f1,f2... or in similar manner.

Comment: @LiorH XML and JSON are semantic-free media types. To be RESTful, you need to provide your own defined media types. You can use JSON and XML as a base, but that alone is not sufficient. For example, look at ATOM, which uses XML.

Answer (score 1):

The question goes away if you stop making the distinction between resources and fields.

If resource `/myresource` has two 'sub-resources' `/myresource/f1` and `/myresource/f2`, then it makes sense to get both at once by specifying a list: `/myresource/f1,f2`.

Comment: No, because a URI has nothing to do with REST.